# What's causing my MLOAD job to fail on Windows Server 2003 when it works on Windows 7 x64 Professional?

Tags: oracle11g, teradata, mload

I created an MLOAD job using OleLoad on my Windows 7 x64 Professional machine.  It loads data from Oracle 11g into Teradata 14.  Everything works great when I run it locally.  When I copy it to a remote Windows Server 2003 SP2 machine and run it, it fails with error code 12 and this message:

```
**** 07:30:57 UTY4203 Attempted to access out of range input data in field
     'LOCATION_CODE', file 'myjob.amj',record number '1'.
**** 07:30:57 UTY4023 Access module warning '33' received during
     'PreserveRestartInfo' operation: 'Attribute name not recognized by attached
     AM'
```

I opened my .amj file on the remote machine to see what it would look like if I regenerated it using OleLoad's UI.  When comparing the two .amj files in Beyond Compare afterward, I was surprised to see that the new .amj is very different.  VARCHAR(214) is changed to FLOAT, VARCHAR(30) is changed to VARCHAR(10), etc.

All TTU 14 assemblies on the remote machine match what I have installed locally.  The only difference I noticed is the verison of Oracle DLL that OleLoad appears to be using.  Here's what OleLoad says on my machine when I click on `Connection Info` for my Oracle connection:

```
Provider
    Name:   OraOLEDB11.dll
    Version:    11.2.0.1.0
DBMS
    Name:   Oracle
    Version:    11.2.0.3.0
```

And on the Windows Server 2003 machine:

```
Provider
    Name:   OraOLEDB.dll
    Version:    9.0.1.0.1
DBMS
    Name:   Oracle
    Version:    11g
```

Now before anyone facepalms with "Well, DUH!  There's your problem!", I'll add that it will cause me a great deal of grief if I had to install a new version of Oracle on my local machine because I have a ton of MLOAD files that I've created for personal utilities (helper loads, if you will, for when the business needs ad hoc report).  I can't upgrade what's on the remote server because I'd run the risk of breaking all of the other MLOAD jobs that are running there.

I just wanted to mention all of that in case it was relevant, but I am hoping that it's not actually the problem and that there's a way I can get my current file to work without having to uninstall/reinstall/upgrade anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the theory proposed at the end of my OP has been confirmed.  I was able to find a machine that had Oracle client 11 installed and migrated my jobs there.  They worked flawlessly, so it is most certainly an issue with Oracle 9 client vs 11.

Comment: If this is the correct reason then please mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @xenodevil I planned on it, but forgot.  Done.